# Sorting 'OR' instead of 'AND' in JPList library

Tags: jquery, html, css, sorting, jplist

I'm trying to use JPList to sort on multiple items. Currently JPList searches like 'AND' (e.g. sort on a item which has the tags, html, php AND jQuery) but i'd like to filter through all the items which contains these tags (e.g. sort on all items which contains html, php OR jQuery). Is there an option to enable this?

Or does someone know a way to achieve this without JPlist?

Underneath is the code (note: this is the default code from JPlist. You can view it here: https://www.jplist.org/documentation/controls/checkbox-path-filter):

```
<h1><a href="https://jplist.org/documentation/controls/checkbox-path-filter">jPList Checkbox Path Filter Control</a></h1>

<div class="box">

    <!-- checkbox path filter control -->
    <label>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            data-jplist-control="checkbox-path-filter"
            data-path=".title"
            data-group="data-group-1"
            name="name1"
            checked />
        Filter by Title
    </label>

    <!-- checkbox path filter control -->
    <label>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            data-jplist-control="checkbox-path-filter"
            data-path=".views"
            data-group="data-group-1"
            name="name2" />
         Filter by Views
    </label>

    <!-- checkbox path filter control -->
    <label>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            data-jplist-control="checkbox-path-filter"
            data-path=".likes"
            data-group="data-group-1"
            name="name3" />
        Filter by Likes
    </label>

</div>

<!-- content to filter -->
<div data-jplist-group="data-group-1">

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="views likes">Views value + Likes value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="title">Title value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="views title">Views value + title value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="title likes">Title value  + likes value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="likes">Likes value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="title">Title value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="title">Title value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="title">Title value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="title">Title value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="likes">Likes value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="title">Title value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="title">Title value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="title">Title value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="title">Title value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="views title">Views value + title value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="likes">Likes value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="views">Views value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="likes">Likes value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="views">Views value</div>
    </div>

    <!-- item -->
    <div data-jplist-item>
        <div class="views likes">Views value + likes value</div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
html, body{
    background: #efefef;  
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 10px;
}

h1{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #212529;
}

a{
    color: #212529;
}

a:hover{
  text-decoration: none;
}


[data-jplist-group]{
    display: flex;
    font-size: 16px;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

[data-jplist-item]{
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #ccc;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 20px 0;
}

label{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
</style>

<script>
jplist.init();
</script>
```

Here's a working codepen demo from JPlist: https://codepen.io/1rosehip/pen/RyYrJG

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding attribute `data-or="example"` in all group of checkbox group.

For example:

```html
<div class="box">

    <!-- checkbox path filter control -->
    <label>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            data-jplist-control="checkbox-path-filter"
            data-path=".title"
            data-group="data-group-1"
            name="name1"
            data-or="example" 
            checked />
        Filter by Title
    </label>

    <!-- checkbox path filter control -->
    <label>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            data-jplist-control="checkbox-path-filter"
            data-path=".views"
            data-group="data-group-1"
            name="name2" 
            data-or="example"/>
         Filter by Views
    </label>

    <!-- checkbox path filter control -->
    <label>
        <input
            type="checkbox"
            data-jplist-control="checkbox-path-filter"
            data-path=".likes"
            data-group="data-group-1"
            name="name3"
            data-or="example"/>
        Filter by Likes
    </label>

</div>
```

It works for me!

Comment: Great, didn't find any of this in de docs. May i ask how did you find out?

Comment: I needed to use it in my application. I just tried every way I could. But yes, the documentation was very incomplete.